# autoTable (3.5.9) not a function

Tags: jspdf-autotable

I have been using jsPDF and autoTable for quite a while and am now trying to update to the latest version of both; jsPDF 2.0.0 and autoTable 3.5.9 were both released a couple of days ago.

jsPDF itself is working fine but I'm getting the "doc.autoTable is not a function" error when trying to use autoTable.

Here's a very simple example:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable"></script>
<script>
  const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF();

  doc.autoTable({
    head: [['Name', 'Email', 'Country']],
    body: [
      ['David', 'david@example.com', 'Sweden'],
      ['Castille', 'castille@example.com', 'Spain']
    ]
  });

  doc.save('table.pdf');
</script>
```

You can see it in action (or not!) at https://jsfiddle.net/r8dah0m7/.

Has anyone managed to get autoTable 3.5.9 working with jsPDF 2.0.0 using downloaded / CDN dist files and if so, what am I missing?

Comment: I can get the version 3.5.9 of autoTable working with the latest-but-one version of jspDF - version 1.5.3. But even though v3.5.9 of autoTable is badged as the release that provides support for jspdf 2.0, it seems that's not the case, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
autoTable(doc, {
head: [['Name', 'Email', 'Country']],
body: [
  ['David', 'david@example.com', 'Sweden'],
  ['Castille', 'castille@example.com', 'Spain']
]
});
```

The documentation for 3.5.9 has not been updated.